# Not showing error message when maximum file size is exceeded in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a form which uploads both an image and a video file. I have set the following in **php.ini**

```
post_max_size = 10M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```

Now the problem is that, if the video file uploaded is not of allowed type, it is showing corresponding error perfectly. But when I tried to upload a video of higher size (23MB), it is not showing file size error. Given below is the controller code where I am uploading the video and image (I am using file upload class) .

Code for **VideoController** :

```
function index()
    {       
        $userid=$this->tank_auth->get_user_id();                        
        if (empty($_FILES['thumb_image']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('thumb_image', 'Thumb Image', 'required|max_length[255]');    
        }

        if (empty($_FILES['video']['name']))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('video', 'Video', 'required');
        }           
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span class="error">', '</span>');
        $data['page']='video/upload';

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) // validation hasn't been passed
        {
            $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
        }
        else // passed validation proceed to post success logic
        {
            $file=$_FILES['video']['name'];
            $thumbfile=$_FILES['thumb_image']['name'];
            $form_data = array(
                            'videolink' => time().$file,
                            'videothumbnail' => time().$thumbfile,
                            'uploaderid' => $userid,
                        );
            $config['upload_path'] = './secure/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'mpeg|mp4|mpg|mpe|qt|mov|avi|movie|wmv|flv|3gp|mkv|dv|m4u|m4v|mxu|rv';
            $config['max_size'] = '10240';

            $extn = end(explode(".", $_FILES['video']['name']));
            $config['file_name'] = time().$_FILES['video']['name'].'.'.$extn;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            $data['upload_data'] = '';

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('video')) 
            {
                $data['msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();  // this is not throwing error
                $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
            } 
            else 
            { 
                $data['upload_data'] = $this->upload->data();


                if($_FILES['thumb_image']['name']!="")
                {
                    $config1['upload_path'] = './secure/';

                    $ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['thumb_image']['name']));
                    $config1['file_name'] = time().$_FILES['thumb_image']['name'].'.'.$ext;

                    $config1['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif|bmp|jpe|tiff|tif';
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config1);
                    $this->upload->initialize($config1);

                    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('thumb_image')) 
                    {
                        $data['msg'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                        $this->load->view('layout/template',$data);
                    } 

                }

                if ($this->Video_model->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) // the information has therefore been successfully saved in the db
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msgresult', 'Successfully uploaded the video !');
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msgresult', 'Please try again. Some error occur during uploading.');
                }

                $data['errors'] = false;
                $data['success'] = true;
                redirect('video/upload');
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me to fix the problem ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you do a `var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());` what do you get?

Comment: it is not displaying anything...

Answer (score -1):

Jenz

Please put below code in index.php so you can get error

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
?>
```